# Sistema de Cadastro E Login Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de cadastro de usuarios em python, utilizando o padrão de arquitetura MVC:

1- criei um arquivo py chamado de main para iniciar o sistema:

```
from controles.ControladorSistema import ControladorSistema

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ControladorSistema().inicia_sistema()
```

2- criei um controlador sistema para chamar as funções do meu menu

```
from telas.TelaSistema import TelaSistema
from controles.ControladorUsuario import ControladorUsuario


class ControladorSistema:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__tela_sistema = TelaSistema()
        self.__tela_usuario = ControladorUsuario()

    def inicia_sistema(self):
        self.abre_tela()

    def cadastra_usuario(self):
        self.__tela_usuario.cadastro_usuario()

    def login_usuario(self):
        pass

    def encerra(self):
        exit(0)

    def abre_tela(self):
        funcao_escolhida = self.__tela_sistema.mostra_opcoes()
        if funcao_escolhida == 1:
            self.__tela_usuario.cadastro_usuario()
            self.inicia_sistema()
        elif funcao_escolhida == 2:
            #self.login_usuario()
            print('AINDA NÃO ESTÁ DISPONIVEL')
            self.inicia_sistema()
        elif funcao_escolhida == 0:
            self.encerra()
        else:
            print('ESSA NÃO É UMA OPÇÃO VÁLIDA')
            self.inicia_sistema()
```

3- criei a tela sistema para mostrar as opções desejadas:

```
class TelaSistema:
    def mostra_opcoes(self):
        print("---------MENU-----------")
        print("Escolha a opcao")
        print("1 - Cadastrar Usuario")
        print("2 - Logar como Usuario")
        print("0 - finalizar")
        opcoes = int(input("escolha uma opcao:"))
        return opcoes
```

4- criei a entidade/classe usuario

```
class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, nome: str, email: str, telefone: str, rg: str, cpf: str, titulo: str, senha: str):
        self.__nome = nome
        self.__email = email
        self.__telefone = telefone
        self.__rg = rg
        self.__cpf = cpf
        self.__titulo = titulo
        self.__senha = senha

    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self.__nome

    @nome.setter
    def nome(self, nome):
        self.__nome = nome

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self.__email

    @email.setter
    def email(self, email):
        self.__email = email

    @property
    def telefone(self):
        return self.__telefone

    @telefone.setter
    def telefone(self, telefone):
        self.telefone = telefone

    @property
    def rg(self):
        return self.__rg

    @rg.setter
    def rg(self, rg):
        self.__rg = rg

    @property
    def cpf(self):
        return self.__cpf

    @cpf.setter
    def cpf(self, cpf):
        self.__cpf = cpf

    @property
    def titulo(self):
        return self.__titulo

    @titulo.setter
    def titulo(self, titulo):
        self.__titulo = titulo

    @property
    def senha(self):
        return self.__senha

    @senha.setter
    def senha(self, senha):
        self.__senha = senha
```

5-criei a tela usuario para obter os dados

```
class TelaUsuario:
    def cadastro_usuario_dados(self):
        print("------CADASTRO------")

        nome = input('nome:')
        email = input('email:')
        senha = input('senha:')
        telefone = input('telefone:')
        rg = input('rg:')
        cpf = input('cpf:')
        titulo = input('titulo:')

        return {'nome': nome, 'email': email, 'senha': senha, 'telefone': telefone, 'rg': rg, 'cpf': cpf,
                'titulo': titulo}
```

6- E por fim criei o Controlador usuario onde colocaria os dados recebidos para o objeto em uma lista de usuarios cadastrados:

```
from telas.TelaUsuario import TelaUsuario
from entidades.Usuario import Usuario


class ControladorUsuario:
    def __init__(self):
        self.usuarios = []
        self.__telausuario = TelaUsuario()

    def cadastro_usuario(self):
        dados_usuario = self.__telausuario.cadastro_usuario_dados()
        usuario = Usuario(dados_usuario['nome'], dados_usuario['email'], dados_usuario['senha'],
                          dados_usuario['telefone'], dados_usuario['rg'],
                          dados_usuario['cpf'], dados_usuario['titulo'])

        if (self.usuarios == None) or usuario.nome != self.usuarios:
            self.usuarios.append((usuario))
        else:
            print("usuario ja cadastrado")
        print(self.usuarios)
```

O problema é que o código permite cadastrar o mesmo usuario várias vezes,ou seja, eu queria validar esse cadastro, não deixando usuários repetidos.

Comment: Qual é a condição de unicidade? CPF? Email? Nome?

Answer (score -2):

Creio que este problema seja solucionado com uma simples validação de atributo-chave. Neste caso, sendo um sistema de cadastro de pessoas, você pode fazer a validação de RG e/ou CPF para indentificar se o usuário já consta na base de dados. Lembrando que o RG varia de estado para estado, ou seja, é bom saber o órgão emissor do mesmo. Caso queira no futuro adicionar um banco de dados ao seu projeto, recomendo estudar sobre MER (modelo entidade relacionamento), no tópico de modelagem de banco de dados ([https://www.ime.usp.br/~andrers/aulas/bd2005-1/aula7.html](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Eandrers/aulas/bd2005-1/aula7.html)).
Para que suas perguntas sejam melhor respondidas é recomendável que vá direto a raíz do problema, contextualizando somente o nescessário. Colocar todos os trechos do seu código pode acabar atrapalhando a indentificação do problema.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).